# Getting {"Specified method is not supported."} exception when perform a query on a list which elemts should be looked up in another list

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, expression

I know it sounds stupid to some extend and vague but I need it :D
I want to perform a query on NH3.1 :

```
var internalReferences = Repository<InternalReferenceRule>
                    .FindAll(e => e.PropertyType.EntityType.Id == 1)

var properties = Repository<IProperty>
                        .Find(p => p.PropertyType.RuleObjects.Any(r => internalReferences.ToList().Any(i => i.Id == r.Id)));
```

the first list (**internalReferences**) is going to be used in the second query which wants to check
if the RuleObjects of a property are available in the first list.

I kinda simplified the original query to make it more understandable.....

anyway, I get the **System.NotSupportedException** from NHibernate and its message is :
**{"Specified method is not supported."}**

any idea?

Comment: sure, thanks for reminding :-) they weren't much though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `internalReferences.Any()` in NHibernate queries because it can't know how to translate that to SQL. Try the following

```
var internalReferences = Repository<InternalReferenceRule>
   .FindAll(e => e.PropertyType.EntityType.Id == 1).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

var properties = Repository<IProperty>
   .Find(p => p.PropertyType.RuleObjects.Any(r => internalReferences.Contains(r.Id)));
```

That should result in a SQL query that uses `IN (:p0, :p1, :p2)`.